# oracle adf how to double click on row and navigate to other page?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and javadeveloper 11.1.2.4.0
I have taskflow with  two jsf page(view1 and view2).view1 navigated to view2 by control flow case.
I want to double click on row of table in view1 and navigate into other jsf page(view2).
I want to know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/56-handle-doubleclick-in-table-170924.pdf which shows how to handle double clicks in tables.